# Power Bi dates not translating

Tags: date, powerbi, translation

I am translating a Power Bi report to Russian and the dates are persistently showing in English.

I have set the report locale to Russian and changed the Date column type to Russian.
[image]

I have created a new column to sort data by month, but the months still show in English.

[image]

Could someone please explain my error? As we want to translate to more languages I do not want to have to rebuild the entire project each time!

Many thanks for advice on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new column is needed in this situation, because the MonthYear column is a *text* column.

1. Create a new month column - example below.
2. Create a Year column from the date column in your dataset (`Year = FORMAT([Date], "yyyy")`)
3. Merge the new month column and the Year column (`RUS_Month_Year = COMBINEVALUES(" ", [RussianMonth], [Year])`

Example of new month column (Russian):

```
RussianMonth = SWITCH(MONTH([Date]),1, "Янв", 2, "Фев", 3, "Мар", 4, "Апр", 5, "Май", 6, "Июн", 7, "Июл",  8, "Авг", 9, "Сен", 10, "Окт", 11, "Ноя", 12, "Дек", "Unknown month number" )
```

With thanks to discussion in [Change month name language](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Change-month-name-language/m-p/105463)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the default language in your Windows settings.
The same applies to Power BI Service.

Locale is just to import the data in the correct format.

If I set my default language to `Spanish`

[image]

And if I go back to `English`

[image]

You need to reopen the Power BI workbook to see the changes.

Comment: Thanks @Angelo Canepa - do I understand you mean I have to go to Settings -> Time & Language -> Windows Display Language -> Russian? I then have my whole Windows GUI in Cyrillic and I will be flying blind. :-o  Also in the Power BI app where the report is one of many, I cannot set the language for the Russian report alone, but only for the whole app - I don't want to change the language settings for the other reports.

Comment: BTW in the app other GUI texts translate correctly to Russian (e.g. default texts like "All" or "Select all"). It is only the _dates_ that show incorrectly. I am not so smart, but I do not understand how my PC's local settings impact language settings in the app after the report is uploaded from Power Bi Desktop.

Comment: That's the only way I know. Sames applies to the Power BI service, for example, if your browser default language is English (US) you will see American dates.